# Get Response-Body of apollo-rest-datasource post request

Tags: javascript, rest, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

how is it possible to get the Response-Body of a Post-Request submitted by the Apollo REST-Datasource module?

dataApi:

```
async postEntry(body) {
return this.post(
  "/domain.com/myService",
  body
).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Resolvers:

```
  Mutation: {
    addEntry: async (_source, { entry }, { dataSources }) => {
    const response = await dataSources.dataAPI.postEntry(entry);
    return response;
},
```

The response only contains different headers. Different to a simple Get-Request where the response contains the body as expected.

Reference: [NPM Site apollo-datasource-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-datasource-rest)

Answer (score 1):

Headers from the response object can be obtained by overriding the `RESTDataSource`'s `didReceiveResponse` method.

Here's a code snippet, if you only care about the headers:

```
async didReceiveResponse(response, _request) {
    // Extract the required headers from response and return them
    return {
        header_name: response.headers.get('header_name'),
        // ...
    };
}
```

Or if you want the headers alongside the default response:

```
async didReceiveResponse(response, _request) {
    return super.didReceiveResponse(response, _request).then((defaultReturnValue) => {
        return {
        ...defaultReturnValue,
        headers: {
            header_name: response.headers.get('header_name'),
        },
        };
    });
}
```